# Rdirecciones con variable POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, http-post

¿Se puede redireccionar a otra **pagina** con datos **POST**?

Para hacer una página de log on pero sin el formulario `<form>`

Comment: De redireccionar si se puede, pero al hacer una redireccion con window.location sin un formulario los datos se pierden, por lo que si que llegarias a la pagina pero con datos vacios, la otra opcion es usar ajax, pero si quieres dirigirte a la pagina de todas maneras no tiene mucho sentido usarlo, puesto que ajax normalmente se usa para no tener que ir hacia esa pagina o no tener que recargarla para obtener los datos, el usar ajax para no tener que usar un formulario deja el mismo problema, es mas conveniente simplemente usar el formulario, puesto que con window.location perderas los datos.

Comment: Otra cosa, es que si no tienes un formulario... a no ser de que los datos no los tenga que ingresar el usuario, como obtendrías esta información sin usar inputs?, es bueno preguntarse si es de verdad conveniente no tener un formulario, puesto que aunque no tengas un formulario, los inputs para extraer información son importantes o algo que te permita extraerlos, entonces es bueno preguntarse si es buena idea simplemente no usar un form habitual con los input?

Comment: Podemos ir incluso un poco mas allá, ajax es una tecnologia que permite enviar peticiones POST y GET sin tener que recargar la pagina o enviarnos hacia ella con la información, es el comportamiento por defecto de ajax, por lo cual los datos son obtenidos en la misma pagina, ajax seria nuestro boleto estrella para poder hacer lo que deseas sin necesidad de un formulario (ajax no requiere de un formulario), sin embargo el mismo inconveniente, la naturaleza de ajax no es la de redirigir hacia alguna parte con datos, por lo que se pierde nuestro boleto estrella.

Comment: Esto debido a que al no ser redirigidos a la vez que los datos son enviados (naturaleza de ajax), los datos llegan al archivo .php, pero una vez usados y terminado los procesos del archivo se destruirá, por lo que ajax no te acerca a la solucion que deseas. recomendaria simplemente usar el formulario para este caso, puesto que los formularios a diferencia de ajax, si redirigen directamente a la pagina con los datos.

Comment: No puedes hacer eso, ya que POST necesita de un submit o algo que la ejecute, solo puedes redireccionar con GET.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar javascript perfectamente para redirigir a otra página pasando valores por post, el truco está en crear el formulario dinámicamente al vuelo usando javascript. Por ejemplo, puedes usar el método que usan en una pregunta resuelta en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Este sería el código:

```
/**
 * envía un petición post a la url especificada desde un form.
 * @param {string} la ruta url a dónde dirigir el post
 * @param {object} añade los parámetros a la ruta
 * @param {string} [method=post] el método a usar
 */

function post(path, params, method='post') {
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  form.method = method;
  form.action = path;
  for (const key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
      hiddenField.name = key;
      hiddenField.value = params[key];
      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Y para usar la función (puedes llamar desde un button o en cualquier evento que desees):

```
post('/pagina_php_que_recoge_el_post/', {name: 'Johnny Bravo'});
```

En este ejemplo, solo pasas un valor llamado name, pero puedes pasar tantos como quieras. Por ejemplo:

```
post('/pagina_php_que_recoge_el_post/', {name: 'Johnny', surname: 'Bravo'});
```

Y en la página php, recoges el valor normalmente con $_POST, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  echo "Nombre: " . $_POST["name"];
?>
```

A todo esto, como bien apunta Riven en los comentarios, tal vez desees usar ajax ya que así, puedes hacer el login sin tener que redirigir al usuario.